# Run Python script 24x7 on windows VM

Tags: python, windows, windows-task-scheduler

Is there any way to run python script on Windows VM continuously. This script should run even computer restarts automatically.

> What I am doing right now?

I have a script called `FooBar.py`, it contains infinite while loop to execute `main()` function continuously. I am running this script on powershell.

> What is problem in this approach?

Sometime this VM restarts automatically or powershell window may close accidentally. This kind of issues causing failure of script execution.

> What I have tried so far?

I tried `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` to run the script but this does not resolve my problem.

Is there any way to run `FooBar.py` script continuously, is there any way in windows scheduler to restart script execution even after computer restarts

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pm2 to schedule the startup of your script](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/). You can find more information on how to use it here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-your-python-script-with-pm2-463238ea0b65

Comment: Hi Jacobo, thanks for your answer but I don;t want to use third party tool as my first solution. Want to do it by Microsoft services itself(if possible).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a module of python named "schedule"
and possibly you can run your code at whatever time you need !

use "pip install schecule" to download the library or module.

for an example i will leave you a pic how to use it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtW5p.png)

i mean job in the picture is a function what you want to do.

if you want it to do for a time interval in secdonds then,you can use
schedule.every(#duration#).seconds.do(#declared function#)

thank you!

Comment: Hi Karthik, Thanks for your answer, even if I use scheduler, I need to run python script which will schedule `foobar.py` script right? then again question raise how should I run it continuously

Answer (score 0):

Create a task in windows scheduler with trigger *On a schedule* and with trigger option *Repeat task every* 1 min. Then in a *Settings* tab there is the dropdown menu *If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:* where you can choose *Do not start a new instance*.